# Cannot update profile, e-mail already exists

Tags: support, status-completed, email

I cannot seem to change my e-mail to `example@abc.com`, getting the message that that is already registered.

Is there maybe another account or some problem with the site? I would like to have only a single account.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you apparently registered under the nickname [Dr. Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406417/dr-touch) last year. Pick whichever you like better and I'll merge the other in.

Comment: Please merge the old Dr. Touch account into the new Cocoanetics account, this is the one I like. Does this preserve my points and all?

Comment: @Cocoanetics: Done. Yes, all posts and reputation are transferred to the new account.